# Build a vector recursively

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-collections

I have a function `f(a: A): A` and an integer `N`. I'd like to write a function that will return the following Vector[A]:

`Vector(a, f(a), f(f(a)), f(f(f(a))), ..., f^{N}(a))`

where `f^{N}` denotes applying `f` recursively `N` times. `N` may be relatively large. I am looking for a solution that will not require reversing a data structure or traversing it more than once. Clearly, there are many ways to do this; I am looking for functional, idiomatic and readable code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

{Vector, List, Array, ...}.iterator

`def iterate[A](start: A, len: Int)(f: (A) ⇒ A): Vector[A]`

> Produces a
>   collection containing repeated applications of a function to a start
>   value. start the start value of the collection len the number of
>   elements contained inthe collection f the function that's repeatedly
>   applied returns **a collection with len values in the sequence start**,
>   **f(start), f(f(start)), ...**

```
scala> def f(x: Int): Int = if(x%2 == 0) x/2 else 3*x+1
f: (x: Int)Int

scala> Vector.iterate(10000, 10)(f)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int] = 
 Vector(10000, 5000, 2500, 1250, 625, 1876, 938, 469, 1408, 704)
```

Or if you really want to implement it yourself, here is a possible solution

```
scala> def iterator[A](start: A, len: Int)(f: A => A): Vector[A] = len match {
     |   case 0 => Vector()
     |   case _ => start +: iterator(f(start), len-1)(f)
     | }
iterator: [A](start: A, len: Int)(f: A => A)Vector[A]

scala> iterator(10000, 100)(f)
res1: Vector[Int] = Vector(10000, 5000, 2500, 1250, 625, 1876, 938, 469, 1408, 
704, 352, 176, 88, 44, 22, 11, 34, 17, 52, 26, 13, 40, 20, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 
1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 
1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 
1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4)
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for introducing me to Vector.iterate!

Answer (score 1):

`(1 to N).foldLeft(Vector(a)) { (acc, a) => acc :+ f(acc.last) }`